# Get a Amazon Route 53 domain to point to Galaxy account

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-route53

I purchased a domain via Amazon Route 53. According to Meteor Galaxy [hosting name](http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-guide.html#select-hostname), I need to point the DNS to `galaxy-ingress.meteor.com`.
Galaxy [Guide](http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/dns.html) lists some options. I am very new to all of this and not sure which one I should follow.
Any idea how to get myDomain.com to point to my Galaxy account as per their instructions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53) helped me a lot.

Summary:
Amazon Route 53 is their DNS server/provider. First make sure your Galaxy account/app is attached to your domain (example.com).

Steps:
1. Set up a CNAME record to map from www.example.com to galaxy-name
2. Set up a redirect from example.com to www.example.com
3  Set up Route 53 servers to be the name servers for example.com

Amazon DNS records for one domain, is called “Hosted Zone” in Route 53, it has nothing to do with “Availability Zone”.